# Regex pattern to choose data BETWEEN matching quotation marks

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

Suppose I had the following string I wanted to run a Regular expression on:

```
This is a test string with "quotation-marks" within it.
The "problem" I am having, per-se, is "knowing" which "quotation-marks"
go with which words.
```

Now, suppose I wanted to replace all the `-` characters **between the quotation marks** with, say, a space. I was thinking I could do so with a regex looking as follows:

```
Find What:      (\"[^"]*?)(\-)([^"]*?\")
Replace With:   $1 $3
```

The problem I'm having is that using this pattern, it does not take into account whether a quotation mark was opening or closing the statement.

So, in the example above, the `-` character in `per-se` will be replaced by a space since it is between 2 quotation marks, but between a **closing and an opening mark** - When I specifically want to look within the text between an **opening and a closing mark**.

How do you account for this in such a regular expression?

I hope this makes sense.

I'm using VB / C# Regex.

---

Just to complete the question (and hopefully elaborate a bit more if necessary), the end result I would like to get would be:

```
This is a test string with "quotation marks" within it.
The "problem" I am having, per-se, is "knowing" which "quotation marks"
go with which words.
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Busted my brain to work this one out, turns out that specifying **non-word** boundaries `\B` does the trick:

### Regex

`\B("[^"]*)-([^"]*")\B`

### Replacement

`$1 $2`

---

### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/dS0bH8

Comment: I'm not getting this to work... Also does this account for matching the quotation marks and only replacing between them?

Comment: Changed it up, try now.

Comment: WOW - It works!!!! You are **AWESOME** - I'm going to accept your answer, but 1 more quick question... Would you know how to change it to account for MULTIPLE `-`s between the quotation marks or is that a completely uglier can of worms??

Comment: Hmmm... I'm sure it's possible, I just can't figure out how to do it :P I've been trying for the last 10 mins or so too, because I'd like to know that answer also.

Answer (score 9):

You are having the same problem as someone who is trying to match HTML or opening and closing parentheses, regex can only match regular languages and knowing which `"` is a closing and an opening one is out of its reach for anything but the trivial cases.

EDIT: As shown in Vasili Syrakis's answer, sometimes it can be done but regex is a fragile solution for this type of problem.

With that said, you can convert your problem in the trivial case. Since you are using .NET, you can simply match every quoted string and use [the overload that takes a match evaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Regex.Replace(text, "\".*?\"", m => m.Value.Replace("-", " "))
```

Test:

```
var text = @"This is a test string with ""quotation-marks"" within it.
The ""problem"" I am having, per-se, is ""knowing"" which ""quotation-marks""
go with which words.";

Console.Write(Regex.Replace(text, "\".*?\"", m => m.Value.Replace("-", " ")));
//This is a test string with "quotation marks" within it.
//The "problem" I am having, per-se, is "knowing" which "quotation marks"
//go with which words.
```

Comment: That is DEFINITELY a cool trick!!! - Thanks for that one!!! And DEFINITELY +1 - I am still curious, though, to see if this could be done with Regex directly, though.

Comment: @JohnBustos: Vache is right, there is no pure regex solution that isn't hackish and brittle.  Just be grateful that you're using a regex flavor (.NET) that not only supports lambdas but makes them so easy to use.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of a regex, a regular method to do this might be more maintainable in the long run:

```
public static String replaceDashInQuotes(this string source, String newValue)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    bool inquote = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        if (source[i] == '\"')
            inquote = !inquote;

        if (source[i] == '-' && inquote)
            sb.Append(newValue);
        else
            sb.Append(source[i]);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Then to use it:

```
var s = @"This is a test string with ""quotation-marks"" within it.
    The ""problem"" I am having, per-se, is ""knowing"" which ""quotation-marks""
    go with which words.";

MessageBox.Show(s.replaceDashInQuotes(" "));
```

Comment: Thanks, John - I know I could do this with a method (and nice way of doing it, BTW), but I was more curious to see **how** to do this with a Regex since I think it might be a great thing to have in my arsenal. THANKS, THOUGH!!!

Answer (score 1):

I will split the string into an array of string, using quotation-mark " as delimiter. 
Then all the strings with an odd number index will be the string within a pair of quotation mark, use your regex on aSplittedString[oddIndex] only, then join the whole array with ".

Comment: Cool idea!!!! +1!! - I'm still curious to see how to do this with only Regex, though, if it was possible.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is explicitly only match strings inside quotes that *have* `-`.

Use this:

```
(\"[^"]*.*?)-(.*?\")
```

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/jK5eL9

The only catch here is that it will only work for single instances of `word-word` in quotes. If you had, say, `"word-word, and word-word"` it will fail.

Comment: Remus, thanks!! - 2 Questions, though... My first one (that I didn't include in the question, is how could I change this to account for multiple `-`s in between the qoutations. And secondly and more importantly, this still changes the `per-se`, which it shouldn;t :(

Comment: When you're getting into conditional stuff like that, you're far better to write a proper function like what John Koerner is suggesting.

Comment: Thanks! - I was **hoping** Regex had some kind of "look-ahead" / "matching" ability to grab that text and then start over where the last match ended....

Comment: It does, but to handle the multiples of capture groups and then adding in negation (do for all of this *except...*) it just to cumbersome and a lot of processing overhead (regex are expensive).